# Delete a liferay portal instance

Tags: liferay-6

Is there any way to delete a portal instance created in liferay 6??

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no way to delete a portal instance in Liferay 6.0. But this might change in further releases (see the comments below this feature request: http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-14023)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to delete the portal instance directly. If you really want to delete it, then you need to go to the portal database and try to delete all the table data with the specific companyId (as the portal instance is identified by companyId).

Answer (score 2):

Check this

[Liferay Wiki - Managing Instances](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Managing+Instances)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to delete portal instance from database. However in Liferay 6.x you will have an option to make it active or not. So If you inactive your portal instance then with that companyId you won't be able to make any action.

Answer (score 0):

A Portlet's code is written just once.
To make a Portlet "instancable" , set instancable = true in liferay-display.xml of that particular portlet.
As far as deleting an instance is concerned, you just need to login as the Admin and delete that portlet from the page. This in no way affets other instances running on various pages of the same portal.

Comment: the question was about portal instances, not portlet instances.